# Line 8:6: 'App' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

Tags: reactjs

i'm starting to learn React.  My practise is to create a list -

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


ReactDOM.render(<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li>l\<li>3</li></ul>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

this is the mistake -

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/index.js   Line 8:6:  'App' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

What's the problem?

Comment: paste the source code directly to your post.

Comment: Are you sure that's the full contents of src/index.js? It doesn't even have 8 lines.

Comment: The error happens on line 8?  In a file with 5 lines?  Sounds like you've made a separate mistake somewhere...